# Como descargar un documento pdf desde mi servidor? Aplicación android

Tags: android, programación-móvil, retrofit, android-volley

Estoy intentando descargar un documento pdf de mi servidor. Ya intente usar Volley y Retrofit pero no he podido. Ahora estoy intentando usar Download Manager de Android usando la ruta del archivo en el servidor pero sigo sin poder hacerlo. Funciona para imagenes pero no para documentos pdf.

Alguien que sepa hacerlo de alguna de las 3 formas? (Volley, Retrofit, Download Manager)

Answer (score 0):

mi amigo espero te ayude.

```
 public static String Download_Archivo(String url_completa, String Nombre_Archivo) {
        try {

            File dir = new File(String.valueOf(valoresGenerales.EXT_STORAGE_DIRECTORY_ARCHIVOS));

            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            // indico URL al archivo
            // nombre que tendr� el archivo

            URL url = new URL(url_completa);
            File file = new File(dir, Nombre_Archivo);

            Log.d("Descarga", "descarga comenzada");
            Log.d("Descarga", "descarga url:" + url);
            Log.d("Descarga", "nombre archivo:" + Nombre_Archivo);

            /* abro una conexion a URL. */
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
            Log.d("Descarga", "CONEXION CORRECTA");
            /*
             * Defino InputStreams para leer desde la URLConnection.
             */
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            Log.d("Descarga", "INPUT STREAM");
            /*
             * leo bytes para el Buffer hasta que no queden mas para leer(-1).
             */
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte) current);
            }

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

            Log.d("Descarga", "descarga lista en  + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) +  segundos");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Descarga", "NO SE PUDO DESCARGAR EL ARCHIVO");
            Log.d("Descarga", "Error: " + e);
            return "2";
        }
        return "1";

    }
```

Pues si te devuelve 1 .. se descargo correctamente 
si es 2 .. ocurrió un error-

el servidor es independiente.  para este método solo pasale la url de la descarga . y el nombre con el que quieres guardarlo.

Answer (score -1):

En la siguiente liga se trata un tema parecido.

Puedes revisar el código, ahí usan las clases HttpURLConnection e InputStream y además, despliegan el pdf en un pdf reader : [android download pdf from url then open it with a pdf reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740228/android-download-pdf-from-url-then-open-it-with-a-pdf-reader)

Si la URL en dónde está ubicado tu pdf no es estática (lo cuál recomiendo) deberías hacer la petición al servidor, éste te regresará la URL y podrás utilizarla como se muestra en el enlace que te paso para descargarlo y hasta visualizarlo.

Comment: Es mejor dar respuestas que incluyen las solucion relevante dentro de ellas, en vez de un link a la solucion ya que los links pueden morir en cualquier momento, o su contenido puede cambiar.